Tiered Storage space on windows 11 results in tiers of size zero
I want to make a tiered storage space using one HDD and one SSD in windows 11
I have followed instructions such as
Storage spaces on Windows 10 and tiering
and
https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/jm3tjx/how_to_set_up_a_tiered_storage_space/
First I make the storage pool, and it lists one 1TB SSD and one 18TB HDD drive with the correct MediaType, resulting in a pool of 19TB.
Then I create two storage tiers, on with media type SSD and one with HDD.
But then each storage tier has a size of 0 bytes and no drives. How do I correctly make a storage tier with the correct drives?
